# How to create a table with a scrollable body without a fixed height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create an html table with a scrollable body so that you can always see the header. I want the table to be inside a div, and have a max height of 100% of the div height. The table items are dynamically generated, so if there are too many items, you will get the scrollbar on the body. But if there are very few items, I want the table to shrink and not use the full height of the div.

I can set the height of the table to 100%, and set the display for tbody to block and give it a max height of 100%. The problem with this is even if there are no items, the table body still uses the full height to show a blank table.

I can set some fixed max-height for tbody, and set height for the table to auto. This way the table shrinks when there are few items instead of showing a blank body. The problem with this is the height is not being controlled by the div anymore.

html:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th > col1</th>
        <th> col 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

css

```
tbody{
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  }

table{
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

div{
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable for this problem. Here is the demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "scrollY": 100,
    "scrollX": true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the details: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html